# In C, how to store two char characters from two char arrays into an integer array

Tags: c, arrays, char, type-conversion, int

I need to take characters from two different char arrays, concatenate them (not add) together and store them into the associated in int array index. I then need to display the ASCII value as the two chars put together when that index is called. for example I have '4' in one char array and 'A' in another char array.. I then want "A4" to be stored into int[5]. When I call int[5] I want to see "A4".

Below is what I've tried so far.

```
int main( int argc, char *argv[] ) 
{


    short cards[52];
    char faces[] = {'A','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','J','Q','K'};
    char suit[] = {'S','D','H','C'};

    for(int i = 0; i<52;i++){
        if(i<14){
            cards[i] = (char)(10*(suit[0] - '0')+ faces[i] - '0');
        }else if(i<27){
            cards[i] = (char)(10*(suit[1] - '0')+ faces[i-14] - '0');
        }else if(i<40){
            cards[i] = (char)(10*(suit[2] - '0')+ faces[i-27] - '0');
        }else if(i<53){
            cards[i] = (char)(10*(suit[3] - '0') + faces[i-40] - '0');
        }
    }

    printf("%c", cards[5]);
}
```

Comment: Ah, homework.  I would think this question requires a byte of shifting.

Comment: *I want "A4" to be stored into int[5]. When I call int[5] I want to see "A4".* -- That's `cards` you're talking about, which is of type `short [52]`, not "int", and as such *cannot* "store 'A4'," but only a `short` integer value. Precision of expression is important when talking about code. Calling `printf( "%c", ... )` expects an `int` argument, not a `short`, and will convert that to `unsigned char`, losing your precious suit / face "encoding" and printing a single character. And what you're doing there with the `10*(suit[0] - '0' )` is wrong on several levels as well.

Comment: Voted to close, "unclear what you are asking". Perhaps take a step back and ask a question about what you are actually trying to achieve -- you've gotten tangled up quite a bit already trying *something*, which any answer to *this* question would have to _untangle_ first.

Comment: One more hint on why your suit / faces encoding won't work. `suit[0]` is `'S'`. `'S' - '0'` is 35... which, multiplied by 10, is 350, *exceeding the maximum value you can store in a `char`*, which is what you cast the result to (before storing it in a `short` array...). Whatever your idea was when you wrote that code, it's not working as intended.

Comment: @DevSolar How is this unclear?? I want to store two char values into an integer value separately?? I'm asking if this is possible.. the reason I want to store them separately is so I can display them together, not as an added value. aka i want to display the ASCII values of 47 and 50, not 97(47+50).

Comment: Do you see how the answer you got basically tells you to scrap all the code you've got and try a different approach? That is what is unclear -- what you describe as your goal in no way matches up with the code you posted. A complete answer would have to address your completely broken code *and* what you actually want to achieve. That is why I -- no offense intended as you are new here -- think this is a poor question, and voted to close this question so you could write up a better, clearer one.

Answer (score 1):

This approach is definitely simplified, if it is done as suggested by @Govind Parmar.  However, were you determined to store the suit and value of the card in a short variable, the following would accomplish that.

Here is utilized the remainder of division (modulus) of 13 to index the face array and the integer division by 13 to index the suit array.  The suit is stored in the card array first.  Then the byte is shifted left.  Hence the value of the suit is stored in the high byte (assuming short is 2 bytes).  The size of the byte is determined with CHAR_BIT from limits.h.  Then a bit-wise or is performed with the corresponding face (value) array.  To print you must shift the short right one byte to print the suit, then mask the high byte with 0s (using 0xFFu) to get the face value.

Again, not sure why you would want to do it this way, but you could.

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {


    unsigned short card[52] = {0};

    unsigned char faces[] = {'A', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '1', 'J', 'Q', 'K'};
    unsigned char suit[] = {'S', 'D', 'H', 'C'};

    for(int i = 0; i < 52; i++) {

        card[i] = suit[i/13];
        card[i] = card[i] << CHAR_BIT;
        card[i] = card[i] | faces[i%13];
    }

    printf("%c%c", card[5] >> CHAR_BIT, card[5] & 0xFFu);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that `sizeof(short)==2` on your system, your character set is ASCII, and you believe that you can populate the short array with the numeric values of your suits and cards side-by-side without any issues.

Going forward with these assumptions, here's what's wrong with your code:

```
suit[x] - '0'
```

This would be the correct way of converting an ASCII character representing a digit into the numeric value of a digit. However, the values in suit are `'S', 'H', 'D',` and `'C'`, so that's not going to work.

```
(suit[0] - '0')+ faces[i]-'0'
```

This is not going to create a representation in `cards[i]` with the value "`<suit-value><card-value>`", each `char` populating one half of the `short`. It's going to create a single `char` with the numeric value of `suit[0] - '0' + faces[i] - '0'`.

```
printf("%c", cards[5]);
```

The correct format for printing out a `short` is `%hd`.

Also, if you're trying to simulate a deck of standard playing cards, where's the value for the card "10" in `faces`?

This was all I could point out with a cursory sweep through your code.

My recommendation to you is to represent the combined suit/face cards as *strings* rather than as `shorts`. Change `cards` to an array of `char[52][3]`, initialize it to zero, then create a loop that goes through `faces` and `suit` and populate `cards` with a string building function like `snprintf`.

Comment: Let’s please not recommend unbounded `sprintf`, especially since “S10\0” is *four* characters.

Comment: @DavisHerring I'd use the letter 'T' to represent 10 if I wanted it in a single char

Comment: And I might use `0`.  My point was that fixed string lengths are easy to get wrong, so it’s best to avoid leading beginners in that direction.

Comment: @DavisHerring: Recommending `snprintf()` for safety is better than `sprintf()` and some critical thinking only if you actually check the return value...

Comment: @DevSolar: It’s not (by itself) undefined behavior even if you ignore it, which is something (and can be a lot in a security context).

Comment: @DavisHerring: No, not UB as defined by the language. But your string might not be at all what you intended it to be, thus violating implied preconditions of later pieces of code, i.e. giving you errors, or even UB, in a different piece of code from where the problem ocurred. You can just as well use `sprintf()` with a precision for the `%s`... -- What I am actually saying is that, the `*printf()` issue being marginal for the answer, it doesn't matter much if the answer mentions `sprintf()` or `snprintf()` when it's done in a sidenote without showcasing the full sanity check rigmarole.

Comment: @DevSolar: Of course there is no substitute for correct analysis—which is why I wrote “by itself”.  But knowing how to use `%.15s` is not enough: you have to know how many digits `%l` produces on your machine and whether `%.2f` might spell out “infinity”.  As you say, `sprintf` is ancillary to the answer, which is all the more reason to avoid betraying its **existence** to novices who are even less prepared to use it than most.